# Kafka Streams processor api allows multi cluster topology?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Using kafka processor API( not DSL) to read from a source topic and write to target topic 
it works fine for a single kafka cluster setup (that is if both source and target topics reside on the same cluster) , but when source and target topics reside on different kafka clusters I am getting NullPointerException for the target processor context

```
Topology
topology.addSource("mySource", "SourceTopic");
topology.addProcessor("SourceStreamProcessor",()->new SourceStreamProcessor(), "mySource");         

topology.addProcessor("TargetProcessor",()->new TargetProcessor(), "Target");
topology.addSink("sink1","OUTPUT_TOPIC1","TargetProcessor");
topology.addSink("sink2","OUTPUT_TOPIC2","TargetProcessor");


Properties sourceProcessorProps = new Properties();
props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "SourceStreamProcessor"); // Kafka Cluster 1
props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "dev_Cluser_xx.org:9092");

Properties targetProcessorProps = new Properties();
props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "targetStreamProcessor"); // Kafka Cluster 2
props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "test_Cluser_xx.org:9092");
```

How can we use kafka streams processor API to write from one topic in one cluster to another topic in a different cluster ?

Comment: How do you build the `KafkaStreams` instance with two `Properties` objects, when its constructor takes only one `Properties` parameter? https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaStreams.html#KafkaStreams-org.apache.kafka.streams.Topology-java.util.Properties-

Answer (score 1):

It is not supported by Kafka Streams to read from one Kafka Cluster and to write to the other Kafka Cluster.

You can process messages within one cluster and than using [Mirror Maker](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_mirror_maker) copy it to the other.